# Why there is no "Top ..." in "Order Option in Kibana Visualization creation

Tags: kibana

I just started learning ELK, the data I am using has the following sample:

```
"YEAR","QUARTER","MONTH","DAY_OF_MONTH","DAY_OF_WEEK","FL_DATE","UNIQUE_CARRIER","AIRLINE_ID","CARRIER","TAIL_NUM","FL_NUM"
2016,1,1,6,3,2016-01-06,"AA",19805,"AA","N4YBAA","43"
2016,1,1,7,4,2016-01-07,"AA",19805,"AA","N434AA","43"
2016,1,1,8,5,2016-01-08,"AA",19805,"AA","N541AA","43"
2016,1,1,9,6,2016-01-09,"AA",19805,"AA","N489AA","43"
2016,1,1,10,7,2016-01-10,"AA",19805,"AA","N439AA","43"
```

When I am creating my first visualization, I want to have a pie chart to show the top stats of "**CARRIER**", in Kibana, below is what I see:

[image]

You can see from the left panel setting "Order", there is no "Top" in the dropdownlist, which causes the chart area shows one pie for the lowest stats of "CARRIER" which in this case is WN, and the rest is grouped into the second pie.

Doesn't make any sense here.

I watched some tutorial videos and there supposed to have more options in the dropdownlist like Top, which means for pie chart creation.

Am I missing anything here? How do I create the needed pie chart?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The "Size" parameter is actually the "Top X" you are looking for.
In your chart, it shows only 1 value, and it chooses the first value by order of ascending.
Change it to have more values.

[image: your chart]